# How can I get the value from string name?

Tags: c#, string

How can I get the value from the file name "I1P706.jpg" that contains between "I" and "P", so in this case it should be "1" ?
in general the length of this value can be more than 1 sumbol

Comment: Will it always be in that position?

Comment: What have you tried? Will it only ever be 1 digit? Always between `I` and `P`? Will these always be at the start of the string? What datatype do you need as result? A string? Int? Something else?

Comment: Your question doesn't show that you have at least read manual.

Comment: Who has downvoted all answers without a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the indexes of I and P, then get the substring starting at iIndex (may need + 1) for the count of the chars between I and P (which is P - I).

```
string myString = "I1P706.jpg"
int iIndex = myString.IndexOf("I");
int pIndex = myString.IndexOf("P");

string betweenIAndP = myString.Substring(iIndex + 1, pIndex - iIndex - 1);
```

Comment: Every answer was downvoted from somebody without leaving a comment. This answer will not return the desired result `1`but `I1`.

Comment: I had highlighted that the +1 may be required. I've put it in the code example now.

Comment: That will give the result 1P, you probably need to change it to this -  string betweenIAndP = myString.Substring(iIndex + 1, pIndex - 1);

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex:

```
var r = new Regex(@"I(\d+)P.*");
var match = r.Match(input, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
    int number = 0; // set a default value
    int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out number);
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want both numbers:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

RegEx rx(@"I(\d+)P(\d+)\.jpg");

Match m = rx.Match("I1P706.jpg");

if(m.Success)
{
    // m.Groups[1].Value contains the first number
    // m.Groups[2].Value contains the second number
}
else
{
    // not found...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "I1P706.jpg";
var indexOfI = input.IndexOf("I");
var result = input.Substring(indexOfI + 1, input.IndexOf("P") - indexOfI - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Regular Expression will give you all characters between I an P only, ignoring case.  This will allow for the number between I and P to grow.

**Example**

```
string fileName = "I1222222P706.jpg";

Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=I)(.*?)(?=P)",
      RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var result = r.Split(fileName).GetValue(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string input = "I1P706.jpg";
// Get the characters by specifying the limits
string sub = input.Substring(1,3);
```

In this case the output will be `1P`.

You can also you the `slice` function

`Slice(1,4)`  of   `Peaceful`     will return              `eac`

Comment: but it length can be more than 1

Comment: @revolutionkpi - You didn't say that.